# List the files in the directory using gwt-filesystems

Tags: file, gwt, filesystems, smartgwt

I tried to list the files in my local directory as well as to read a file. But was not able to do it. Can any one give me sample code to get the list of files in a directory using gwt-filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends from where you are reading. You can't obviously read from the client due to security issues (any HTML wouldn't let you do that). However, you could obviously read the list of files in a folder from the server side.